# Why can't I acess my repository in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: git, repository, google-earth-engine

For reference, I already solved my problem but the reason and solution for the problem might be of interest. When I opened my Google Earth Engine code editor, one of my repositories was red and without access to my scripts or Revision History. The only thing shown was the following error message:

```
Load error: <html> <head> <title>500 Internal Server Error</title> </head> <body> <h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1> 
The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.<br /><br /> </body> </html>
```

I tried to find the error on the internet and I only found that a 500 error might be temporary and not something the user can solve, bu it wasn't the case. I was working on this repository in the past few days and even pulled it to my computer, made some GIT commits there and pushed it back. I also pushed a tag (`git push --tag`) but the repository worked a bit more after that.

Comment: Are you posting your own answer?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes! Just did it. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is with the tag itself. For some reason, Google Earth Engine has problems with GIT tags, and somebody like me could push a tag to GEE for some reason (I did it just to have a backup of my versions), like we do on Github. To solve the problem, you can just remove your tag from the GEE remote:

```
git push --delete origin v0.1.0
```

Where `v0.1.0` should be replaced by your tag name and `origin` should be replaced by your remote name.